# Tried to load angular more than once with SockJS and StompJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once` if I include below libraries together

[StompJS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/master/lib/stomp.min.js)

[SockJS](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1/sockjs.min.js)

Working with angular version `1.5.7`

Does anyone facing the same issue while using websockets?

**UPDATED**

Below are the js libraries which I have included

```
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
'bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js',
'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
'bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js',
'bower_components/angular-elastic/elastic.js',
'bower_components/checklist-model/checklist-model.js',
'bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
'bower_components/ui-select/dist/select.js',
'bower_components/toastr/toastr.js',
'node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp.js',
'vendor/scripts/sockjs.min.js'
```

As I said If I remove either of `sockjs.min.js` or `stomp.js`, console does not show WARNING of load more than once

Comment: can you show your script loading declarations.....this message will occurs when angular.js  file content load more than once.check in that way

Comment: @SaE I am using grunt to compile all the vendor files, I have only one include of `angular.js`

Comment: ok thats fine,what i want to tell you that,as you know jquery library is a part of angular js right,if we wont load the jquery.js specially still its works in our project as it is loaded by angular.......like this i think some of your js files are loading the angular.js code again.....its only my opinion.

Comment: @SaE I have added js libraries in question.

Comment: try to load them before 'bower_components/angular/angular.js' and check for the warning

Comment: @SaE I already did that, not working.

Comment: got any solution??